How Can I Resolve F1 Continue and F10 BIOS Setting Error on My HP ProBook 450 G1, and due to this Touchpad Not Working?
I'm experiencing a recurring issue with my HP ProBook 450 G1. On startup, I often get an error message prompting me to press F1 to continue or F10 to enter BIOS settings. Additionally, sometimes when this error occurs, my laptop's touchpad stops working.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Changing the CMOS battery.
Creating a bootable USB using the HP Media Recovery tool.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I’ve been attempting to flash my BIOS as a potential solution. However, when I start the recovery process, it begins to load and then restarts. Instead of installing the image, it bypasses this step and boots directly into Windows 10. The BIOS flash is not happening with the USB either.
I’m quite stuck at this point and unsure what to do next. Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions to resolve this BIOS error and get my touchpad working again? Any advice on successfully flashing the BIOS would also be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

You have a hardware problem as I am sure you know. This site is for the support of the Ubuntu OS. Hardware issues are off topic, Sorry. You need to send it for repair.

You mention that your system boots directly to Windows, but this site is about Ubuntu only. Do you actually use Ubuntu? If you do, can you [edit] your question to clarify what makes you believe that your issue is not hardware-related? Because hardware-related issues are not on-topic here, as David mentioned above. Thanks!

Your system is missing some files, which causes errors. Please reinstall the win11 system.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
